# Can facebook username change? Is it unique? Is it suitable for our own internal ID?

Tags: facebook

Basically I allow people to sign up to my app via facebook.

I wonder whether I should store the facebook ID or facebook Username.

The username is more attractive. However, can it change? Is it unique?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The username is more attractive. However, can it change?

Yep! A user can change his username once. (https://www.facebook.com/help/162586890471598/)

> Is it unique?

Yes.

Comment: if users can only change his username once, it's still useful as an id I guess.

Comment: Jimmy - that is absolutely not correct; the user ID will never change